# how to cancel a notification that received when app run in the background?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

the following code works for me when the notification received while the application run on the foreground.

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.cancel(notificationID);
```

but when the notification received while the application on the background then it does not work (the specific notification that I try to delete is not deleted).
cancelAll() functtion delete all background and foreground received notifications but I don't want to use it because I want to delete a specific notification.

I am getting notification via FCM(Firebase cloud messaging).

Android 10

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use

> notificationmanger.cancelall();

That will close tour all notifications from any where so you can create them again i hope its helpful

> Public Int Helpnotification = 6:

> Notificationmanger.notify(notification , Helpnotification);

Comment: i want to cancel a specific notification.. i  in the question that i dont want to use cancelAll.

Comment: @N.Sam Ok you give reuqest number in values xml and call both in create and cancel it from any where get resources i mean notification id

Comment: .sorry i did not understand your solution.. i am sorry i am new to Android..

Comment: what do you mean by request number?

Comment: @N.Sam you set number for notification id thats int set your this number on public int or value xml file than call it from there to set notification id see the answer

Comment: er reflex, the notification id is the orderId, it is an app that receive orders and i want that when user open the order its specific notification will be deleted.. notificationManager.notify(orderId,notificationBuilder.build());

Comment: @N.Sam i tell you create int in your class put your orderid in it than create your notification and set your notification id from that int, create same int in class which you want to cancel notification and use same int for cancel noti id it will work and finally in android 8+ cheack that you create your notification chanell when you create and cancel and call your notification channel before any changes it must work